# Missing artifact com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:jar:${appengine.sdk.version}

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I am getting the below error while creating a maven project in eclipse 3.0

> **Missing artifact com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:jar:${appengine.sdk.version}**

Can someone help me out?

Comment: please provide a more details to better understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your template substitution is not working.  Have you tried either making sure you have a maven property appengine.sdk.version define, or substituting the placeholder with a fixed version of appengine-tools-sdk?